# A command to get the sync status of a Dropbox file

Tags: linux, dropbox

I'm using Dropbox on Ubuntu. I'd like to detect the sync status of a file in my public directory (specifically: is it uploaded?) with a command / script. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `filestatus`:

```
dropbox filestatus /path/to/file
```

For more help see:

```
dropbox help
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Thor's answer, if the `dropbox` command is unavailable, you may need to install it. It can be downloaded from the dropbox website with:

```
curl -Lo bin/dropbox.py 'https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py'
chmod +x bin/dropbox.py
```

where `bin` is some bin directory on your path, either in your home directory or perhaps `/usr/local/bin` which may require the commands be run with `sudo` or as root.

The script may then be used like

```
dropbox.py help
dropbox.py filestatus /path/to/file
```

This is referenced by *Dropbox* at https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/linux-commands and documented at *The Unofficial Dropbox wiki*: https://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/using-the-official-dropbox-command-line-interface-cli.